# React Native disable keyboard in TextInput but allow cursor

Tags: react-native

I'm currently building an order page that takes in only selected characters for my TextInput element.

My requirement is that when I focus on TextInput, the keyboard doesn't appear but I can still point the cursor around in the TextInput.

Tried using editable={false}, works for keyboard not appearing but disables cursor.

Is there a workaround to this where I can hide my keyboard but still use cursor?

[image: I want to hide the phone keyboard, and just use my own built on screen keyboard]

Comment: Did you find any workaround? I am too struck on this.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<TextInput showSoftInputOnFocus={false} />
```

It will hide the keyboard when you focus on the text input.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not currently posisble in React Native, see this [Github thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14045#issuecomment-421887173)